# Find ActiveRecord objects by week in the year

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I have reports with a date in them. Now I want to find all the reports by a given week of a year. What I have is this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :date

  def self.find_by_week(week, year)
    Model.all.find_all do |model|
      model.date.year == year and model.date.s­trftime("%­W").to_i == week
    end
  end  
end
```

But I am afraid that this solution might be not very performant when the Software has accumulated the thousands of reports expected for it. Is there a better solution?

If it matters, I'm using SQLite3 in development, but the production DB will be a MySQL. Though I'd like a solution that is DB-independent, if possible...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in a date range:

```
dates = Date.commercial(2012,40)..Date.commercial(2012,41)
Model.where(:date => dates)
```

There are more parameters available for `Date.commercial` - the above will give you Monday to Monday. To set more specific dates/times, have a [look at the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-commercial).

Comment: So it includes the second monday? I must remove the last day?

Comment: I assume it would do Monday, October 1 00:00:00 to Monday, October 8 00:00:00, meaning the second Monday wouldn't be included, however, I haven't used this much. I would recommend setting up a few tests.